# I want to open a webpage from java passing username and password to it

Tags: java

I am working with a small webpage using java and servlets. From my webpage I want to open a third party website without showing its login page. I mean to say authenticating it from Java and entering its home page. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: How does the 3rd party website authenticate?

Comment: The more I read this question the more questions I have... Do you mean you want a form on a site you are creating that when its submitted you are logged in on the 3rd party site AND sent over to a 3rd party site? Or do you want to keep them on your site and simply use the 3rd party for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the server (your app) and the client (the browser). Even if you (the server) would authenticate successfully, the client still wouldn't be authenticated, as you have no way to pass the authentication data to the client (cookie restrictions etc.).

So what you *could* do is read the HTML data of the foreign site on your server and stream it out to your client. But the performance would be miserable, you would have to rewrite every single link on the pages and most of all: you would probably violate copyright laws. Don't do it!

I don't think there is a sane solution for you, unless the author of the other site agrees on a shared authentication mechanism with you.